# How Can I Do Multiple Alarm With AlarmManager?

Tags: android, android-alarms

I have an Android application. I have to add 4 tasks to run the same job at 9.15am, 11am, 2pm, and 4pm. Is there a way to run the same job 4 times ? I could do only one task with alarmamanager .

How do I configure multiple alarm ?

Comment: *I could do only one task with alarmamanager* ?? I can run **at least** 5 at the same time

Comment: I guess some code could help.

Answer (score 0):

Create 4 PendingIntents that call the same Service/Activity/Broadcast but use a different request code for each of them.

```
Intent serviceToStart = new Intent(context, YourService.class);
PendingIntent execute915am = PendingIntent.getService(context, 1, serviceToStart, 0);
PendingIntent execute11am = PendingIntent.getService(context, 2, serviceToStart, 0);
PendingIntent execute2pm = PendingIntent.getService(context, 3, serviceToStart, 0);
PendingIntent execute4pm = PendingIntent.getService(context, 4, serviceToStart, 0);
```

Comment: Why same Service/Activity/Broadcast? I may use different sound to play and every alarm is in different time? I used 4 pending intents  and 4 broadcasts . I is ok only for alarm? How can I handle it? And can you help with code?

Comment: 1: you said 'run the same job'. 2: sure, if it works then its fine. You could also use one BroadcastReceiver and supply informations on which job to use as an extra in the Intent. 3: what do you mean by 'how can I handle it'? Register the BroadcastReceiver in the Manifest and implement the logic in the receiver(s). 4: No.